# Is there a way in Discord JDA (server-side) to disable User Join \ User Leave audio?

Tags: discord-jda

is it possible to mute VC join | leave audio from the server for all users? or is that a feature that doesnt exist? I know about the user variant Settings > Notifications > Sounds > User Leave|Join|Moved but I would like it server wide as users will be constantly switching channels automatically as assigned from the bot, however I'd rather not ask every user to manually do so client side..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible. All of these sound effects are client-side and cannot be controlled by bots.